# pysolr update document with error

Tags: python-2.7, pysolr

**update:** Pysolr Version: 3.2.0

**This seems a bug in solr. when update nothing in an operation, it will delete this doc.**

Former I used code in [using pysolr in atomic update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415659/how-to-make-atomic-updates-to-solr-using-pysolr), but I made error in following case.

Now a document schema maybe like this:

```
doc = {
   'id':    ...,
   'title': ...,
   'body':  ...,
}
```

I have indexed a batch of docs and now I want to update every doc with a new field anchor_text. Here is my code:

```
solr = pysolr.Solr(url_solr)
doc_update = {
   'id': ...,
   'anchor_text': [a,b,c,...]
}
solr.add([doc_update], fieldUpdates={
    'anchor_text': 'set'
})
```

But I found some of original docs were **removed** only with **id** field left.
Something like this after update:

```
doc = {
  'id':...
}
```

Especially, for those whose anchor_text field are empty lists, the original docs are removed. While others are not.(Probably I guess because I only see several cases).

I've looked at the source code but found nothing valuable. What's going on here?

What are the correct way to use pysolr in update document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across the same issue (python-3.6, pysolr-3.6, solr 6.4.1). As I couldn't find any more information online, I used a requests workaround which I'll leave here in case it's of use to anyone.

```
import requests
import json

def update_single_solr_field(doc_id_field, doc_id, field_update_name, field_update_value):
    # Updates a single field in a document with id 'doc_id'.
    # Updates only the 'field_update_name' field to the 'field_update_value', leaving other fields intact

    base_url = 'http://localhost:8983/'
    solr_url = 'solr/mysolrcore/'
    update_url = 'update?commit=true'
    full_url = base_url + solr_url + update_url
    headers = {'content-type': "application/json"}

    payload = [{
        doc_id_field: doc_id,
        field_update_name: {
            'set': field_update_value
        }
    }]

    response = requests.post(full_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

    return response

# example
id_field_name = 'id'
doc_id_to_update = '1700370208'
field_to_update = 'weight_field'
field_to_update_value = 20000
response_update = update_single_solr_field(id_field_name, doc_id_to_update, field_to_update, field_to_update_value)

print(response_update)
```